# no se ve uno de los campos en mi recyclerview que he agregado

Tags: java, android, base-de-datos, firebase

Agregue a mi clase modelo Actividades.java el campo saldoActual y no logro mostrarlos en mi recyclerView que estoy cargando desde firebase.

Cuento con dos formularios donde en el primero ingreso actividades y en el segundo ingreso gastos lo que estoy intentando es que cada que se ingrese un gasto se reste en la actividad que le corresponda, asi tengo mi database:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego de hacer la resta necesito actualizar el campo saldoActual de mis actividades y aun no he hecho la resta por ahora estoy intentando mostrar el saldoActual en mi recyclerView pero no logro mostrar ese campo aun:

Esta es mi clase de modelo Actividades:

```
public class Actividades {
    public String idAct,estado,fechaActividad,nombreActividad,numeroProjecto,tipoActividad,usuario,valorPresupuesto,saldoAct;

    public Actividades(){ }
    //public Actividades(String itm) { }


    public Actividades(String saldoAct,String idAct,String estado, String fechaActividad, String nombreActividad,String numeroProjecto, String tipoActividad, String usuario, String valorPresupuesto) {
        this.saldoAct = saldoAct;
        this.idAct = idAct;
        this.estado = estado;
        this.fechaActividad = fechaActividad;
        this.nombreActividad = nombreActividad;
        this.numeroProjecto = numeroProjecto;
        this.tipoActividad = tipoActividad;
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.valorPresupuesto = valorPresupuesto;
    }

    public String getSaldoAct() {
        return saldoAct;
    }

    public void setSaldoAct(String saldoAct) {
        this.saldoAct = saldoAct;
    }

    public String getIdAct() {
        return idAct;
    }

    public void setIdAct(String idAct) {
        this.idAct = idAct;
    }

    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public String getFechaActividad() {
        return fechaActividad;
    }

    public void setFechaActividad(String fechaActividad) {
        this.fechaActividad = fechaActividad;
    }

    public String getNombreActividad() {
        return nombreActividad;
    }

    public void setNombreActividad(String nombreActividad) {
        this.nombreActividad = nombreActividad;
    }

    public String getTipoActividad() {
        return tipoActividad;
    }

    public void setTipoActividad(String tipoActividad) {
        this.tipoActividad = tipoActividad;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getValorPresupuesto() {
        return valorPresupuesto;
    }

    public void setValorPresupuesto(String valorPresupuesto) {
        this.valorPresupuesto = valorPresupuesto;
    }

    public String getNumeroProjecto() {
        return numeroProjecto;
    }

    public void setNumeroProjecto(String numeroProjecto) {
        this.numeroProjecto = numeroProjecto;
    }
}
```

Al parecer el valor es nulo ya que intente traer el dato solo de SaldoActual y me muestra en mi LogCat null : `D/Mensaje:: null`
Tampoco tengo errores en codigo, mi problema es que no esta llamando el dato que necesito, asi se ve mi recycler View:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta la clase ActividadesAdapter.java:

```
public class ActividadesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ActividadesAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private ArrayList<Actividades> actividadesList;

    public ActividadesAdapter(ArrayList<Actividades> actividadesList){
        this.actividadesList = actividadesList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_recycler_act,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(mView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Actividades actividades = actividadesList.get(position);

        holder.tvNombreA.setText(actividades.getNombreActividad());
        holder.tvNumeroP.setText(actividades.getNumeroProjecto());
        holder.tvValorP.setText(actividades.getValorPresupuesto());
        holder.tvTipoA.setText(actividades.getTipoActividad());
        holder.tvFechaA.setText(actividades.getFechaActividad());
        holder.tvEstadoA.setText(actividades.getEstado());
        holder.tvUsuarioA.setText(actividades.getUsuario());
        holder.idAct.setText(actividades.getIdAct());
        holder.tvSaldoA.setText(actividades.getSaldoAct());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return actividadesList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView tvNombreA;
        TextView tvNumeroP;
        TextView tvValorP;
        TextView tvTipoA;
        TextView tvFechaA;
        TextView tvEstadoA;
        TextView tvUsuarioA;
        TextView idAct;
        TextView tvSaldoA;

        public View view;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            view = itemView;

            this.view = itemView;
            this.tvNombreA = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvNombreA);
            this.tvNumeroP = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvNumeroP);
            this.tvValorP = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvValorP);
            this.tvTipoA = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTipoA);
            this.tvFechaA = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvFechaA);
            this.tvEstadoA = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvEstadoA);
            this.tvUsuarioA = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvUsuarioA);
            this.idAct = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idAct);
            this.tvSaldoA = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSaldoAct);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity4.class);
                    intent.putExtra("idAct", actividadesList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getNombreActividad());
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

La clase donde carga mi RecyclerView:

```
public class ListaAct extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    public ActividadesAdapter actividadesAdapter;
    public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public ArrayList<Actividades> mArrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista);
        //setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); //Función que se encarga de bloquear la rotación de pantalla
        mArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        actividadesAdapter = new ActividadesAdapter(mArrayList);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvActividades);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(actividadesAdapter);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DataLegalizaciones");
        getActividadesFromFirebase();

    }
    private void getActividadesFromFirebase(){

        mDatabase.child("Actividades").orderByChild("estado").equalTo("aprobado").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Actividades actividades = ds.getValue(Actividades.class);
                        //String saldoA = actividades.getSaldoAct();
                        //Log.d("Mensaje: ",""+saldoA);
                        mArrayList.add(actividades);
                    }
                    actividadesAdapter = new ActividadesAdapter(mArrayList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(actividadesAdapter);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Realmente no encuentro que es lo que me hace falta, Agradezco cuaquier ayuda o recomendación con mi código

Comment: Si imprimes Log.d("Mensaje: ", ""+getValorPresupuesto()); si obtienes valor?

Comment: realmente no comprendo tu ejemplo talvez querias decir Log.d("Mensaje: ", ""+actividades.getValorPresupuesto()); pero ninguna funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

en la clase Actividades  cambia el nombre de la variable

```
saldoAct
```

por

```
saldoActual
```

las variables deben tener los mismos nombres en firebase y en tu codigo para que se puedan mapear correctamente, no olvides cambiar los respectivos

```
getSaldoActual()
```

y

```
setSaldoActual()
```

Comment: Me parece que tienes razón, no puede encontrar la propiedad "saldoAct" por eso no agrega el valor, esperemos a ver que dice el OP, saludos.

Comment: Efectivamente era esa linea muchas gracias, ademas también tuve que modificar mi Adaptador en la linea holder.tvSaldoA.setText(actividades.getSaldoActual()); Gracias!!